# How to make button link clickable in php echo?

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

I have this code but every time the button is clicked it directs to just `story.php` neglecting the other details.
I've tried using javascript but it seems using form action is the nearest possible way for me to achieve this:

```
<form action='./story.php?u=$id'><button type='submit' class='w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i>$likes  Like</button> 
    <button type='submit' class='w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom'>   
</form><i class='fa fa-comment'></i>  Comment$comments</button>
```

Comment: What JavaScript?  What "other details"?  Please clarify what the actual problem is.

Comment: that `</form>` tag shouldn't be inside `<button></button>`.

Comment: Look at the source of the code. Are the variables showing, or the values? While the button submits the form, there are no inputs for it to actually submit other than `u`.

Comment: i've edited the code and yes the variable is showing the correct link on the source code.
But when its clicked it just takes me to story.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting here. A form `submit` will go to the `action` of said form. You have nothing that is taking control of the `submit` event to preventDefault of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **method** for it, either post or get

```html
<form action="./story.php?u=12" method="post" >
<button type='submit' class='w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> $likes  Like</button> 

<button type='submit' class='w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom'><i class='fa fa-comment'></i>  Comment $comments</button> 
    
</form>
```

it works fine now